# What is the "5th Edition Adventures" book series?

Tags: dnd-5e, product-identification, books

I recently was looking through an online games store for tabletop games and in the section for D&D 5e I  found a book series called "5th Edition Adventures".

I have never seen these books, the don't seem to be part of the "normal" D&D 5e books as the art is entirely different, the only thing I can see that would reverence what it is part of is the following quote from the description :

> This is an introductory adventure for those playing the 5th Edition of the world's best known and oldest RPG.

I am talking about [this](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/160855/A0-The-Rising-Knight--Adventures-for-5th-Edition-Rules) book. There seem be be a lot of these. from A0 to A6 and from C2 to C7. I also found a S1 and an U2 (this seems to be how they number the books. ).

I have no idea what these books are and it is very difficult to Google because I can only find stuff related to D&D 5e when googling it.

Does anyone know what these books are about?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a D&D 5e-compatible adventure by [Troll Lord Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_Lord_Games). They're most notable for being the publisher of [*Castles & Crusades*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castles_%26_Crusades) — and being Gygax's last publisher.

The odd numbering system is how old (1st edition) adventures were numbered - and while I can't attest to this, I believe this is a series of 5e compatible adventures with an old-school feel.

You can click on Troll Lord's link on the site to see [their available catalog](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/86).

When you ask *if anyone knows what these books are about* - I am not sure if you mean either of the following:

- What is the narrative content of the adventure?
- Are these books (un)official 5e material?

While I haven't played any of TLG's 5e-compatible content, I did run Goodman Games' [*Into the Borderlands*](https://goodman-games.com/store/product/original-adventures-reincarnated-1-into-the-borderlands/), their official 5e conversion of *Keep on the Borderlands*, for almost two years. 3rd-party content quality varies by author and publisher — but much of it is very good. That book was beautiful and was a blast to play.

I think you'll find quite a bit of people out there who heartily endorse 3rd party content.

Comment: I beleve the reason for calling it "5th Edition" is that third-party publishers are wary of using the name "Dungeons & Dragons", a trademark of Wizards of the Coast. That, and it sorts at the top alphabetically on RPGNow.

Comment: i did indeed mean if they where (un)official 5e material but the added info is always welcome

Comment: @QuadraticWizard: Indeed, the name "Dungeons & Dragons" (and abbreviation "D&D") is referenced as "Product Identity" and as "not Open Content" in [the OGL](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf).